# How to get 3-character time zone display names in Java 8 time library?

Tags: java, java-8, timezone, java-time

When DST is active, I can print EDT with `java.util.TimeZone` as follows:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").getDisplayName(true, TimeZone.SHORT) -> Returns "EDT"
```

I want to get the same 3-character with Java 8's new time library. I try this but I only get ET:

```
ZonedDateTime.now().getZone().getDisplayName(TextStyle.SHORT, Locale.US) -> Returns "ET"
```

Is there any way to get 3-character display names (EST, EDT, PST, PDT, etc.) in the new library, depending on the DST status?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get using `DateTimeFormatter` this way

```
ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("z"))
```

`ZoneId` in your `ZonedDateTime` doesn't have that information accually .

Comment: It seems there is no exact counterpart for this line as you said: `TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York").getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())`